# elasticsearch: can I defined synonyms with boost?

Tags: elasticsearch, synonym

Let's say `A`, `B`, `C` are synonyms, I want to define `B` is "closer" to `A` than `C`

so that when I search the keyword `A`, in the searching results, `A` comes the first, `B` comes the second and `C` comes the last.

Any help?

Comment: Have you got any solution for this? I guess this is not possible in ES.

Answer (score 9):

There is no search-time mechanism (as of yet) to differentiate between matches on synonyms and source field.  This is because, when indexed, a field's synonyms are placed into the inverted index alongside the original term, leaving all words equal.

This is not to say however that you cannot do some magic at index time to glean the information you want.

Create an index with two analyzers: one with a synonym filter, and one without.

```
PUT /synonym_test/
{
settings : {
  analysis : {
    analyzer : {
      "no_synonyms" : {
        tokenizer : "lowercase"
      },
      "synonyms" : {
        tokenizer : "lowercase",
        filter : ["synonym"]
      }
     },
     filter : {
       synonym : {
         type : "synonym",
         format: "wordnet",
         synonyms_path: "prolog/wn_s.pl"
        }
      }
   }
  }
}
```

Use a multi-field mapping so that the field of interest is indexed twice:

```
PUT /synonym_test/mytype/_mapping
{
   "properties":{
     "mood": {
       "type": "multi_field",
       "fields" : {
          "syn" : {"type" : "string", "analyzer" : "synonyms"},
          "no_syn" : {"type" : "string", "analyzer" : "no_synonyms"}
       }
     }
   }

}
```

Index a test document:

```
POST /synonym_test/mytype/1
{
  mood:"elated"
}
```

At search time, boost the score of hits on the field with no synonymn.

```
GET /synonym_test/mytype/_search
{
  query: {
    bool: {
      should: [
          { match: { "mood.syn" : { query: "gleeful", "boost": 3 } } },
          { match: { "mood.no_syn" : "gleeful" } }
      ]
    }
  }

}
```

Results in **_score":0.2696457**

Searching for the original term returns a better score:

```
GET /synonym_test/mytype/_search
{
  query: {
    bool: {
      should: [
          { match: { "mood.syn" : { query: "elated", "boost": 3 } } },
          { match: { "mood.no_syn" : "elated" } }
      ]
    }
  }

}
```

Results in: **_score":0.6558018,"**

Comment: Also see here: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/most-fields.html

Comment: Am I misreading your answer or are you boosting your synonym field instead of the non-synonym field? But you say you are going to boost the non-synonym field?